# How to disable quantity and in-stock options for Virtual Products?

Tags: magento2, stock, quantity, virtual-products

I'm new at Magento. I want to list real estate like home or office space in the site. Im doing this as a virtual product. Quantity and in stock options are no relevant to these products. Hence would like to disable those options in the site.
I could not find solution anywhere to fix the same.

Do we have any solution to fix this issue?
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `Manage Stock` to `Off`.

Comment: Where is this??

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `if` condition to check that the product is virtual or not.
Like below code

```
 if($product->getTypeId() != "virtual"){
    //show product stock options
 }
 else{
//show stock options
 }
```

**Hope this will make a way for you to get your job done! Happy learning**

Comment: Thanks for the reply Asish.
In which file shall I add this particular piece of code?

Comment: @sravaniG that depends on where you want to this?? On list page or in product details page

Comment: On product details page

Comment: on `app/design/frontend/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` **find**  <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>` find this and add extra condition on this `if`

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable the quantity and in-stock options for the virtual product, navigate catalog_product_view.xml file, and extends the block/container and then in your template check if the product is of type virtual then don't show the product stock , else show the product quantity for other products.

Your/module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Your\Module\Block\HideStock" name="hide_stock" template="Your_Module::hideStock.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Similarly create a block for the layout. i.e. Your\Module\Block\HideStock and add the corresponding functions

In your phtml i.e.  Your_Module::hideStock.phtml

```
 if($product->getTypeId() != "virtual"){
    show product stock options
 }
 else{
hide stock options

//your code here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="field qty">
          <!--  <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?/*= /* @escapeNotVerified */ //__('Qty') */?></span></label>-->
            <div class="control">
                <input type="hidden"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Just comment above code in template\product\view\addtocart.phtml and make input type "hidden".

Note : Copy above template(addcart.phtml) into your theme then do changes